# Copy field content from one row to another according to Product ID and language ID

Tags: sql, copy

I have database descriptions. in this case i must copy from one row to 2 another. 
Product ID is same for all 3 rows but language Id is deferent. How i can copy field description from row where is Product Id 157 or any another and Language Id is 1 to row where is Product ID 157 (there is lot of diferent IDs) and language id is 7.

Can someone help me to do for all Product IDs with one sql commands

Thanks a lot.

Comment: please share ur schema.

Comment: Some sample data and expected result, and perhaps I'll understand...

Comment: Shema. I wave database name product and table name description
I share link picture for better  [link](http://9globe.com/sql.jpg) 
red squere is data what must be copied in blue squere.

Comment: Also show us your current query, and describe what's wrong with it.

Comment: On link I add in comment you will se a picture from phpmy admin. I Must copy data from red squere to row (blue squere) for every separate product IDs.

Comment: Have you tried the query I posted in [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32225457/3409662)?

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question correctly, then use below

```
update my_table
  set description_field = (select description_field
                           from my_table
                           where product_id = 157 and language_id = 1)
where product_id = 157 and language_id = 7
```

Just make sure that the `inner query` returns only one `description`!

Comment: I have more than 1000 Product IDs . can someone help me add data for all product ids with one sql commands. You can see shema on [link](http://9globe.com/sql.jpg)

Comment: update my_table a set a.description_field = (select b.description_field from my_table b where b.product_id = a.product_id and b.language_id = 1)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your table is called "description"

```
UPDATE description d1
INNER JOIN description d2
ON d1.product_id = d2.product_id
AND d2.language_id = 1
SET d1.description1 = d2.description1,
    d1.description2 = d2.description2,
    d1.description3 = d2.description3
WHERE d1.language_id != 1
```

It will update the description1, description2 and description3 fields of all the rows where language_id is set to something else than 1, with the description1, description2 and description3 from the rows with the same product_id, but where language_id is set to 1.

---

There may be DBMS where you can use subqueries instead of an `INNER JOIN`, but it won't work in MySQL, it will result in an error (#1093), because you can't select from the table you're updating.